# Extracting NDWI, NDVI pixel values from raster image to one attribute table using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.0, and I want to have an attribute table of my study area with 3 columns. The first column will represent each pixel of my study area(1,2,3...,Final_Pixel). The other 2 columns will be, one for NDVI and another one for NDWI. For instance x axis will be NDVI_Value and y axis will be NDWI_Value.

Can I do it with a different way instead of using Fishnet?

For example:

[image]

Comment: The first column will represent each pixel of my study area, by that you mean the x and y coordinates of the pixel?

Comment: Indeed for instance, x will be NDWI_Value and y will be NDVI_Value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you must have 2 rasters; an NDVI and a NDWI. Assuming they are the same cell size, cover the same extent and have the same coordinate system (you do not specify this in your question) then a simple solution is this:

1. Convert NDWI into a point dataset
2. Convert NDVI into a point dataset
3. Rename grid_code field in NDWI point dataset to NDWI
4. Rename grid_code field in NDVI point dataset to NDVI
5. Run Join Field, joining on pointid and passing over NDVI to the NDWI dataset
6. Export attribute table to your required format.

Comment: When I run join field, only null values appear to my new table, do you know why is that? @Hornbydd

Comment: Joining on wrong field?

Comment: I have selected the following, Input table : NDWI table, Input Join Field: pointid, Join Table: NDVI table, Join Table field: NDVI_value @Hornbydd

Comment: Only null values on the new field* @Hornbydd

Comment: Your join table field needs to be point ID also that's how you match rows. Then the final parameter are the fields you want to pass over, suggest you read the help on the [Join Field tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/join-field.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Although you asked for a solution using `ArcGIS Pro`, I do not have it in the PC I am using now so I will suggest a solution using `QGIS` instead. **Assuming** you data are in raster format (NDVI.tif, NDWI.tif etc), and they have the same extent, CRS etc. You can use the tool called `Point sampling tool` (you can install it from the Plugins -> Manage and install plugins.

You then create a grid (or fishnet as it called in ArcMap) by going to Vector -> Research tools -> Create grid. Then you need to specify the distance between your point (Horizontal and Vertical space).
[image: create grid]

Finally, go to Plugins -> Analysis -> Point sampling tool. in the first bar you insert the point shp, and below that you select your raster data.

[image: pst]

This will create a point shp with the pixel values of your raster data.